# signWithCustomMethod error [ Invalid assertion format. 3 dot separated segments required. ]

Tags: firebase, react-native, basic-authentication

```
firebase.auth().signInwithCustomToken().then().catch()
```

It is separated by 3 dots. 
what should I pass in the parameter of signInwithCustomToken() method?
id or some token?
P.S.createCustomToken() is deprecated so i am using the signInWithCustomMethod directly. Also i am still using the free version, i.e biling is not enabled in firebase console.

Answer (score 1):

Just cast string token to `AuthProviderToken` in this way:

```
if let credential = AccessToken.current?.tokenString { //String Token unwrapped
     let authCredential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: credential) // Auth Credential
...
```

Happy Coding!